# Finding the Position of the Minimum Neighbor for Each Element in a Large Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a large matrix ($6020\times 8452$), and I want to create a new matrix where the relative position of the minimum neighbor is each element in the matrix. For example, if I had the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\2 & 3 & 4\\3 & 4 & 5\end{bmatrix}$,

I want the program to return

$\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 4 & 4\\2 & 1 & 1\\2 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

To explain, $9$ represents that the specific element is the minimum of all its neighbors; $4$ represents that the neighbor directly West of the specified element is the minimum of all neighbors; $2$ represents that the neighbor directly North of the specified element is the minimum of all neighbors; and $1$ represents that the neighbor directly Northwest of the specified element is the minimum of all neighbors. The numbering scheme is not an important aspect of the problem, I just used this scheme in order to make the question more understandable.

My problem is that the program I made takes too long to be a reasonable way to work with my matrix. Is there some way to speed up this program a significant amount?

Also, a few quick notes about the matrix. The matrix is about half zeros, so I am using a SparseArray. Moreover, the maximum value of the whole matrix is approximately $397$. The minimum value is approximately $237$.

```
matrix = ArrayPad[dataSet, 1, 500.];

Table[Position[{matrix[[i - 1]][[j - 1]], matrix[[i - 1]][[j]], 
matrix[[i - 1]][[j + 1]], matrix[[i]][[j - 1]], 
matrix[[i]][[j + 1]], matrix[[i + 1]][[j - 1]], 
matrix[[i + 1]][[j]], matrix[[i + 1]][[j + 1]], matrix[[i]][[j]]}, 
Min[{matrix[[i - 1]][[j - 1]], matrix[[i - 1]][[j]], 
 matrix[[i - 1]][[j + 1]], matrix[[i]][[j - 1]], 
matrix[[i]][[j + 1]], matrix[[i + 1]][[j - 1]], 
matrix[[i + 1]][[j]], matrix[[i + 1]][[j + 1]], 
matrix[[i]][[j]]}]], {i, 2, Length[matrix] - 1}, {j, 2, 
Length[matrix[[1]]] - 1}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a speed up, but a way to access each element only once instead of twice would be `Ordering[{(*list the 9 neighbourhood elements here*)}][[1]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on [Martin Büttner](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2305/martin-b%C3%BCttner)'s comment this is perhaps best handled using `Ordering`.  We can apply it to subarrays produced by [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html), though we will need to [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) them first.  I shall further use [`PartitionMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html) to improve memory performance.

A starting array:

```
SeedRandom[0]
a = RandomInteger[9, {4, 6}];
a // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  7 & 0 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\
>  8 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 2 & 1 \\
>  0 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 6 \\
>  5 & 5 & 8 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The process:

```
<< Developer`

PartitionMap[Ordering[Flatten@#, 1][[1]] &, a, {3, 3}, 1, 2, 99]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  6 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
>  3 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  3 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
>  2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The numbers correspond to placement within:

```
Partition[Range@9, 3]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  4 & 5 & 6 \\
>  7 & 8 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Notes:

- The padding element, `99` in the example above, must never be the minimum.
- In cases with multiple minimum values the position of the first is used.

---

If it is vital that the central position always have priority over the neighbors with regard to the minimum value we can simply reorder the elements before `Ordering` is applied.  This changes the meaning of the numbers in the result but since that is arbitrary already it should not matter.

```
PartitionMap[
  Ordering[Flatten[#] ~RotateLeft~ 4, 1][[1]] &,
  a, {3, 3}, 1, 2, 99
]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
>  2 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  1 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 7 \\
>  7 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 6 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The numbering now corresponds to:

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  9 & 1 & 2 \\
>  3 & 4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct implementation using MapIndexed.

```
map = {{1, 1} -> "NW", {1, 2} -> "N", {1, 3} -> "NE", {2, 1} -> "W", 
      {2, 2} -> "0", {1, 3} -> "E",{3, 1} -> "SW", {3, 2} -> "S", {3, 3} -> "SE"};
mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}};
mat0 = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}};
mat = ArrayPad[mat0, 1, Infinity];
f[{ii_, jj_}] := Module[{i = ii + 1, j = jj + 1, m},
  m = mat[[i - 1 ;; i + 1, j - 1 ;; j + 1]];
  First@Position[m, Min[m], {2}] /. map
  ]
MapIndexed[f[#2] &, mat0, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To use numbers instead of NW,SW,etc.... change the map to

```
map = {{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 2, {1, 3} -> 1, {2, 1} -> 4, 
   {2, 2} -> 9, {1, 3} -> 2,{3, 1} -> 1, {3, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 1};
```

You did not give numbers to all locations, so I made up ones.

[image: Mathematica graphics]